# Is there any way to create a setup which update the current version of an application?

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I created a simple C# WPF program, which run various setup of different program by clicking on buttons, so it automates some task when I have to configure PCs.

Initially, I used the function **Publish** of VS, so when I do changes to the code and deploy again the user click on **install update** and he has the latest version (fantastic), but this application require admin rights because it install features, create folders such as I wrote above, so I add to my project the `app.manifest` for running my app with the correct rights. I published again the project, but I got an error, I read that `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` option and **ClickOnce** can't exists at the same time, I found some workaround but not very functional, below the code:

```
     public MainWindow()
     {
        InitializeComponent();            
        AdminRelauncher();
     }

     private void AdminRelauncher()
     {
        if (!IsRunAsAdmin())
        {
            ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
            proc.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            proc.FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase;
            proc.Verb = "runas";
            try
            {
                Process.Start(proc);
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBoxResult mess = MessageBox.Show("Program must be run as admin! \n\n" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsRunAsAdmin()
    {
        try
        {
            WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(id);
            return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

After that i create a setup using **Microsoft VS Installer Projects**, it works well but every time I do changes or fixes to the code I have to deploy the setup -> unistall the old program -> install the new, this is a waste of time.

So there is any way to deploy a sort of installer or something else which check for application update?

Or better run as administrator the application installed with ClickOnce?

Comment: Microsoft VS Installer Projects can overwrite their previous installations, that shouldn't be a problem. What's the problem you're experiencing that forces you to have to uninstall the old program? Are you maybe not increasing the version/build number? If I remember correctly this has to not only be done in the application but somewhere in the installer configuration too.

Comment: @Longoon12000 ok I'll try now, and do you know if is possible to publish the setup instead of copy and paste it to the release folder?

Comment: Publish as in...? If you just want the output of your installer project to be copied to some other path you can specify a post-build event in the property window of the setup project ([here](https://i.imgur.com/GrcLQbg.png)).

Comment: @Longoon12000 publish into a network foldere. Anyway I tried to launch the setup with an high version of the program, but I got error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best you create another app, a Launcher, whose purpose is to check if a local file on your other app have a version number below the one stored at your database/ftp. If it is true, then your Launcher will download from your ftp the new version and overwrite the old one. It is like I work on my current C# projects :P

Of course, you can also make your Launcher the main executable, at the end of the update check, it can run your program, and thats all, your users only have to run the launcher to update and/or run your main program.

Comment: Great, could you provide some code or references, where I can start to learn how to implement it?

Comment: In order to connect to the ftp and get the file which contains the current version number, you must start to create an FTP object with
`FTP ftp = new FTP("your.host.com");`
`ftp.Connect("user", "password");`
Now you can get the file from the ftp using ftp.GetFile(), read the version number, and compare with the version number of your local file.
If version is not the same, then use ftp.GetFile() again in order to get the .exe of your program.
I hope it helps... It is hard to share with you my code cause is part of a huge project.